# Yammer embedded via iframe in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, iframe, yammer

I am trying to show a Yammer group feed via iframe on a SharePoint page (Sharepoint version 2010). The Yammer feed is embedded via the embedding code from Yammer on a simple html page.

This page I am showing via the "iframe web part" in SharePoint. It works fine in both Firefox and Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer.

Can you please help me and let me know what the reason could be? I already added the Yammer URL to the trusted sites in IE.

Many thanks!